# How to "Query Syntax" group "x" by x.Something1 and x.Something2?

Tags: c#, linq

I was practicing LINQ query syntax and method syntax to learn how to convert the expression to another syntax.

I was having a problem on how to convert this method syntax to query syntax.

```
  var groupNew = dogs.GroupBy(x =>new { x.Color, x.Breed});
  var groupNew2 = groupNew.SelectMany(x => x);
```

Ouput:

[image: Method Syntax Output]

This is the query syntax I've coded I thought could work which the compiler does not accept.

```
var groupQuery = from d in dogs
                 group d by d.Color and d.Breed into newGroup
                 select new { age = newGroup.Key, color = d.Color, breed = d.breed };
```

And if I make it right for testing the new type, the new type only returns age from the query unlike the method syntax.

Test Data:

```
Dog[] dogs = new Dog[] {
            new Dog(2, "Poms", "Green"),
            new Dog(10, "Poms", "Green"),
            new Dog(3, "Poms", "Green"),
            new Dog(4, "Askal", "White"),
            new Dog(2, "Askal", "Black"),
            new Dog(2, "German", "Brown"),
            new Dog(2, "Shitsu", "White"),
            new Dog(3, "Dalgom", "Brown"),
            new Dog(1, "Dalgom", "Brown"),
            new Dog(2, "Dalgom", "Black"),
            new Dog(4, "Chiwawa", "Blackpink"),
            new Dog(3, "Chiwawa", "Blackpink"),

        };
```

Comment: For one thing in the method syntax you're grouping by color and breed - you're only grouping by color in the query syntax. I'd expect `group d by new { d.Color, d.Breed }` in the query syntax. (If you could post a [mcve], it would be easier for us to try things, by the way.)

Comment: @JonSkeet This what I've tried so far "group d by d.Color and d.Breed into newGroup" which is wrong. So I have to create new{} to group the result with many grouping options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your LINQ query in query syntax:

```
var groupNew = from dog in dogs // GroupBy
               group dog by new { dog.Color, dog.Breed } into groups
               select groups;
var groupNew2 = from g in groupNew // SelectMany
                from dog in g
                select dog;
```

Or in a single query:

```
var groupNew2 = from g in (
                  from dog in dogs
                  group d by new { d.Color, d.Breed } into groups
                  select groups
                )
                from dog in g
                select dog;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need cuz I also want the query to return dogs.